# Variations of the convolution of 1 to n based on all permutations of 1 to n

Tags: number-theory

There are three methods that produce different sums.  I give example for each method.  Method A: 1*(1+2+3+4) +2*(1+2+3) + 3*(1+2) + 4*(1) = 35.  Visualize stationary  4,3,2,1 and above it 1,2,3,4, which travels term by term over each term in the sequence beneath it.  One term above another means to multiply them and keep the sum of all such products.  Method B: 1,2,3,4 is stationary and above it is 1,2,3,4 which passes over term by term to give 1*(4+3+2+1) + 2*(4+3+2) + 3*(4+3) + 4*(4) = 65.  Method C: Stationary 1,2,3,4 and above it travels 4,3,2,1 to give 4*(4+3+2+1) + 3*(4+3+2) + 2*(4+3) + 1*(4) = 85.  Each method for each 1 to n will produce a formula for any value of n.  The question is: Is this the kind of problem that can be solved by a symbol manipulation program in a computer?  There are four possible was to arrange one set of n terms above another if the two sets contain different terms; many possibilities and sums exist.

Comment: It's not very clear to me what you are asking.

Comment: Once you understand the operations from the examples, ask yourself if you've ever seen computer software than can find the equation for the sum of all the results.

Answer (score 1):

It is simple with Computer Algebra Systems such as Mathematica. For example:

```
{Sum[i Sum[j, {j, 1, n - i + 1}], {i, 1, n}], 
 Sum[i Sum[j, {j, i, n}], {i, 1, n}], 
 Sum[i Sum[j, {j, n - i + 1, n}], {i, 1, n}]} // InputForm

{(n*(1 + n)*(6 + 5*n + n^2))/24,
 (n*(1 + n)*(2 + 7*n + 3*n^2))/24,
 (n*(1 + n)*(2 + 5*n + 5*n^2))/24}
```

So the answer to your questions is yes.

Comment: ThanXXXX gobs for your answer.  Are you guys worried that AI will put you out of business?  Instead of simple consecutive numbers, imagine if you used some of the sequence of terms in OEIS for strange formulas.  It would certainly be one way of contributing sequences.